# turbolinks + UJS. remote form submit multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, ujs, remote-forms

I have following simple code

`rails 4.2.1` + `turbolinks (2.5.3)`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
```

(I haven't any custom JS code)

```
doctype html
html
head
  title Dummy App
  = stylesheet_link_tag    :application, 'data-turbolinks-track' => true, media: :all
  = javascript_include_tag :application, 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
  = csrf_meta_tags
body
  .body
     = yield
```

I visited few pages and after I press "submit" button on `remote: true` form. And submit request was executed many times.

It looks like UJS was initialized on each `document.ready` or `page:load`

Can it be bug? or I did somthing wrong?

**UPD**

it was typo in slim markup

```
doctype html
html
head
```

Comment: Any chance you're including jquery_ujs in the body somewhere?

Comment: No chances. I found same topics and checked my code many times. JS in HEAD tag.

Comment: it was typo in markup. html tag had wrong level

```
    doctype html
    html
    head
```